Оптимизация работы OpenVPN соединения на базе Mikrotik c удалёнными пользователями
столкнулся с таким вопросом, как дать понять удалённым компьютерам 10.8.8.0/24 имена и ip адреса хостов в локальном сегменте 192.175.0.0/21. Всё работает путём записывания в файл hosts в операционной системе windows, но чувствую это не хорошее решение.
Выполнены типичные решения такие как прописывания локальных DNS серверов в профиль ovpn.
Указания на самом сервере OpenVPN DNS адреса.
